# Will buying a new cheap video card let me have a third monitor painlessly?

Tags: multiple-monitors, graphics-card

So I have a Radeon HD 5770 and after a lot of stress I'm giving up on plugging three monitors into it.  Is my best/easiest option to just buy a cheap PCI video card, pop it into my motherboard and plug a monitor into it?

I've never had two video cards simultaneously before.  Is there any risk of driver conflict?  Do I need another ATI card?  Any other suggestions would be great.

Comment: Depends on the OS you are using. Apparently VISTA restricts the graphics driver to a single driver, windows 7 allows multiple drivers

Comment: @Joe Taylor: Technically it is a single driver model, eg 2x4800 but not a 4800 and a 4700. This was huge oversight by Microsoft, but now corrected.

Comment: Some of the 3rd gen  Intel i7 processors support 3 monitors and so, instead of a video card, in theory you could buy a new motherboard (it would need 3 separate vid connectors on it) and new 3rd gen CPU.

Answer (score 1):

Yes adding an additional PCI videocard *should* work, and there *should* be no driver conflicts *(but no guarantees)*

If you want it ridiculously easy get a [USB graphics adapter](http://www.google.com/search?q=usb%20graphics%20card&ie=UTF-8) instead.

Comment: I've heard these have issues with performance, do you have first hand experience with one?

Comment: @Andrew - Only briefly. It's no good for gaming. But for email, web-browsing and terminal use it worked without a hitch.

Comment: Cool, I'm not a big gamer.  As is, when I play games on my current setup I only use one monitor anyways.  I spent about $90 to get one shipped to my house, will know Friday if this long battle is over!